# Should I use a fieldset for this?

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I have a queryset. I'm trying to display a feedback form for each of items in the queryset. What's a good way to approach this? Attach the model to a fieldset and then iterate through the forms in a fieldset, displaying the model information? Or loop through both the queryset and fieldsets separately in the template?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean formset? A Django formset is helpful if you have multiple, identical forms on the same page.

A model formset sounds like it would work based on your description.

Link to the docs:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: +1 for giving it the old college try at interpreting the question